# android. apply different styles for text in listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I make http-request to my server and get some json back. whatever is returned is parsed and represented in these 2 variables:

```
String status = item.getString("status");
String date = item.getString("date");
```

Also I have ArrayAdapter, ArrayList and ListView

```
arrayListResults = new ArrayList<String>();
resultsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.resultsList);
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.results_list_item, arrayListResults);
resultsList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

After fetching results i'm adding them to the arrayList, like so:

```
arrayListResults.add(status + ":\n" + date);
```

and then notify that dataset changed.

What I need is to apply different styles to status and date.
I'm familiar with

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + status+ "</b>")
```

bur i can't figure out how I implement it in my particular case.

results_list_item layout is

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:textSize="15sp" >
```

Comment: Html styles not applied to your textview??

Comment: @Lokesh problem is that i'm not setting text text directly to textView here, I use arrayListResults.add() method so textView.setText() never used. So the question is where in my code should I use textView.setText()?

Comment: @AndrewMalinnkov you need to implement `Custom Adapter` over here with Your `Custom Layout` and set `textView.setText()` in `Custom Adapter getView(....)`

Comment: you need to set in your Custom Adapter.